# What is a word for fake seriousness, especially when you are intending to be funny

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that means saying something with an insincerely serious tone, usually for comedic effect. I feel like the word facetious is close to what I'm looking for, but not exactly.

"Surely, you can't be serious," they said.
"Of course I'm serious," he replied [word-ly], "And don't call me Shirley."

Comment: Does irony apply?

Comment: "The phrase tongue-in-cheek is a figure of speech that describes a statement or other expression that the speaker or author does not mean literally, but intends as humor or otherwise not seriously." (wiki) Couldn't add an answer, so commenting here.

Answer (score 125):

The word **deadpan** is probably the best fit. It can be used as an adjective or adverb (or a noun or a verb):

> **adjective**
>
> marked by or accomplished with a careful pretense of seriousness or calm detachment; impassive or expressionless:
>   *deadpan humor.*
>
> **adverb**
>
> in a deadpan manner:
>   *He spoke his lines utterly deadpan.*
>
> <sub>[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/deadpanned) Unabridged
>
>   Based on the Random House Dictionary, © Random House, Inc. 2018.</sub>

Comment: has always connoted unemotional, disinterested to me. Serious ≠ deadpan. E.g. in the OP's example the replier "Of course I'm serious" wouldn't be deadpan, but rather concerned, or taken aback by the asker's doubt. At least to me

Comment: @theonlygusti really? It's the first word I thought of as I read the question ... the only better answer (which isn't a single word) is *mock-serious*.

Comment: *Deadpan* is also a verb: "'Of course I'm serious,' he deadpanned."

Comment: [_tongue-in-cheek_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tongue-in-cheek) also fits: the notion being that one is keeping a straight face when saying something funny in a serious way by biting one's tongue.

Comment: @theonlygusti I think you're not getting the joke in that passage of text, which is a play on words between "surely" and "Shirley".  It's from the movie Airplane, which is a tongue in cheek comedy playing on the popularity (at the time) of "disaster movies".  "Deadpan" can be used to denote a lack of emotion, but it's most commonly used in the context of the delivery of comedy.

Comment: @MaxWilliams The *character* was being serious, the *actor* was using a deadpan tone, i.e., I think you are both correct. `he replied [word-ly]`: I think a book or the movie script would use "seriously" here because the character is not trying to be funny, but a director speaking to the actor would tell them to be deadpan.

Comment: I would be *really* cautious about using "deadpan" in these kinds of situations - greater context is highly relevant here. Given *just* the snippet in the question without other context, "deadpan" would leave me unsure if the speaking character was actually "fake serious" and doing deadpan delivery for comedic effect or genuinely serious and naturally deadpan in affect. To me "deadpan" gives information about facial-features/tone-of-voice/etc, and says nothing about sincerity or any other aspects of the "inner world" of the person being described.

Comment: Well, it's a comic line delivered in a serious style.  In a silly comedy like Airplane it's probably pointless to try to get too deeply into the inner lives and motivations of the characters.  Either way, deadpan is the perfect word IMO.

Comment: Deadpan is the answer to the OP's question. However the example given is a poor one as explained by Quantic's comment

Answer (score 29):

**straight faced**   [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/straight-faced)
     straight′-faced′ (-fāst′) adj.
     straight′-faced′ly (-fāst′lē, -fā′sĭd-lē) adv.

> A face that betrays no sign of emotion.

As in:

> He was a very straight-faced prof, but he has a tremendous sense of
>   humor.
>
> She was watching me totally straight-faced and it took a couple of
>   seconds before it dawned on me that I'd just been had.

And here is an article on some famous straight-faced comedians:  [article](http://unrealitymag.com/movies/eight-comedians-who-did-serious-well/)

Answer (score 15):

The word that came to my mind was "dry wit". A search of "dry wit" will bring you to Laurel's answer. Laurel's answer is better anyway, and more common.

> **dry**
>   14. Humorous in an understated or unemotional way: *dry wit.*
>   [definition of dry](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/dry)

Answer (score 11):

**sarcastic**

[Sarcasm](http://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-sarcasm.html) is an ironic or satirical remark that seems to be praising someone or something but is really taunting or cutting. Sarcasm can be used to hurt or offend or **can be used for comic affect.**

**sardonic**

[Sardonic](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/sardonic) comes from the Greek adjective Sardonios, which actually describes a plant from the island of Sardinia that supposedly made your face contort into a horrible grin...right before you died from its poison. **The Greeks used sardonic for laughter, but we only use it when someone's humor is also mocking or ironic.**

Answer (score 5):

This is a form of understated humor. As others have suggested "deadpan" and "dry wit" are typical forms of understated humor. There is another word that describes it, and that is ["Laconic"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laconic_phrase)

A deadpan reply is usually also laconic, delivered tersely, without too many words and faking disinterest.

> (...) “Don't look at me,” he said in a conversational tone. “I am slipping a little Browning into the pocket of your oilskin. There — do you feel?” “It is very heavy,” she said. “What am I to do with it?” “Shoot,” he said laconically (...)

Comment: What is your example quote from? It sounds like a book I would very much enjoy reading. :)

Comment: @Missmonicae I just Googled "he said laconically". I'll try to track it down.

Comment: Ha, this answer is the 3rd Google result for me now but it seems to be by Edgar Wallace. I only find the quote in GB results for collections, so if you don't turn anything up I'll ask on Lit.SE.

Comment: @missmonicae I am on vacation so not exactly at my computer, so sorry if it is going to take me a while :P

Answer (score 2):

**droll**

[curious in a way that provokes dry amusement](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/droll)

Answer (score 1):

What about the word [**whimsical**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/whimsical) (made or done for fun, not seriously):

> "Surely, you can't be serious," they said. "Of course I'm serious," he replied **whimsically**, "And don't call me Shirley."

Another good one would be [**glibly**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/glib) (speaking or spoken in a confident way, but without careful thought or honesty):

> "Surely, you can't be serious," they said. "Of course I'm serious," he replied **glibly**, "And don't call me Shirley."

Answer (score 1):

Mock-sententiously is an expression commonly used in talking about this sort of thing, if the type of serious air in question is self-important.

You might find [this discussion of satire](https://books.google.com/books?id=20l9BgAAQBAJ&pg=PA103&lpg=PA103&dq=pretending%20to%20be%20serious%20literary&source=bl&ots=OsQ1Qeot4v&sig=kc5DQZqwoM_MU_-2AywOCFgE6d8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9j_D9g4jaAhUEwWMKHWCZBLMQ6AEIOjAC#v=onepage&q=pretending%20to%20be%20serious%20literary&f=false) helpful, as it defines the use of mock-heroic in parody.

Comment: I've only heard this as "mock seriousness".

Answer (score 0):

For this context, I would consider **slyly**. Even if it might not be exactly what are you *asking* for, it still might be the word you are *looking* for. From [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/slyly%22dictionary.com%22):

> in a roguish or mischievous way:
>
> > Some were serious, while others slyly winked at the camera.

"Surely, you can't be serious," they said. "Of course I'm serious," he replied **slyly**, "And don't call me Shirley."

Answer (score -5):

**[jestINGly](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/jesting)**

verb (used without object)

6. to speak in a playful, humorous, or facetious way; joke.
7. to speak or act in mere sport, rather than in earnest; trifle (often followed by with):

   *Please don't jest with me.*

(of course this "thing said or done" can vary according to many criteria, but is still applicable across this "comedic spectrum").

Comment: Where did this definition come from? I've never heard of any such word. Do you mean jestingly?